# Navigation + Tabbed + Stacked + Modal Window Fullscreen

Tags: react-navigation, expo

Please have a look [complex-app](https://snack.expo.io/@webloper/complex-app)
Here is the flow of the app

`Splash Screen` -> `Check Authentication` -> `Sign In` Or `Sign Up Screen` -> `other wise Home Screen with tabs and header` -> then `Modal Screen to show camera`!

After doing lots of changes I am stuck here, need help what’s wrong or I miss here. thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the link and source code for my question [custom-navigation-2](https://snack.expo.io/@webloper/custom-navigation-2)